# How to do Cassandra data modeling for aggregate counts?

Tags: cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

Let's say I have customer orders data coming into my service and I would like do some reporting on this data. All customer orders are saved in a Cassandra table so that I can get all orders for a given customer:

```
TABLE customer_orders

store_id uuid,
customer_id text,
order_id text,
order_amount int,
order_date timestamp,

PRIMARY: KEY (store_id, customer_id)
```

But I would also like to find all the customers with a given number of orders. Ideally I would like to have this in a ready to query table in Cassandra. For example "get all customers who have 1 order".

Therefore I have a table like this:

```
TABLE order_count_to_customer

store_id uuid,
order_count int,
customer_id text

PRIMARY KEY ((store_id, order_count), customer_id)
```

So the idea is when an order arrives both of these tables to be updated.

So I create a third table:

```
TABLE customer_to_orders_count

store_id uuid,
customer_id text,
orders_count counter,

PRIMARY KEY (store_id, orders_count)
```

When an order arrives:

1. I save it in the first table
2. Then update the counter in the third table by incrementing it with 1.
3. Then I read the counter in the third table and insert a new record in the second table.

When I need to find all the customers with a given number of orders I just query the second table.

The problem with this is that counters are not atomic and consistent. If I update the counter say to 3 there is no guarantee that when I read it next in order to update the second table it would be 3. It could be 2. Even if I read the counter before I do the update of the counter it could be some value from several steps back. So no guarantee either.
Please note that I am aware of the limitations of the counters in Cassandra and I am not asking how to solve the issue with the counters.

I am rather giving this example, in order to ask for some general advice on how to model the data in order to be able to do aggregate counting on it. I can of course use Spark to do aggregate queries directly on the first table in my example. But it seems to me that there could be some more clever way to do this and also Spark would involve bringing the whole table data into memory.

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about using the CQL Batch command.  https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_reference/batch_r.html

You can use this with all your steps to keep all your steps in one logical atomic transaction where either they will all succeed or fail.   However this functionality does have a performance penalty.